# Python Pandas .to_sql() Error 22018 when using chunksize > 1

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

I'm trying to insert a dataframe back to SQL Server and have found the various "faster" ways using .to_sql(method='multi'); but I get a conversion error whenever I try to send more than one row at a time.

```
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=server;DATABASE=DB;Trusted_Connection=no;UID=user;PWD=pass")

datatypes = {'PolicyID': db.Integer(), 'DecPageID': db.Integer(),
          'ManualID': db.Integer(), 'Tag': db.String(36),
          'Value': db.String(36), 'ID1': db.Integer(),
          'ID2': db.Integer()}

engine = db.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)

df_final.to_sql("XML_New", con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, method='multi', chunksize=2, dtype=datatypes)
```

The dataframe has the same columns, int64 type for the Integers and object for the String fields. The 'Value' column contains mixed values (numbers, strings, and null), but the first value is 'Y'.

If I use `chunksize=1` the code runs fine. If I use any larger chunk, it will error with:

> DataError: (pyodbc.DataError) ('22018', "[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Y' to data type int. (245) (SQLExecDirectW)")>

I don't understand why it is trying to convert the 'Y' into an integer when the source field is an object, and I specified the destination field as String. The table in SQL Server is created correctly specifying varchar(36) for the 'Value' column. I have tried various DRIVERs to no avail.

Is my only option to dump to .csv and import directly to SQL Server?

Comment: Try prepending a SPACE to each Value, to force uniform string type? Or focus on sending all the string rows at once, then all the integer rows. (Also, please don't show us your secret credentials.)

Comment: You could also try using `create_engine(connection_uri, fast_executemany=True)` and omitting `method='multi'` from the `to_sql` call. pyodbc's `fast_executemany` code has built-in checks for heterogenous column data that may help in such circumstances, albeit at the expense of performance.

Comment: Thank you both. @GordThompson, your suggestion worked; but the performance won't cut it for the size of table (narrow, but long). (Can't believe I forgot to anonymize, so thank you for pointing it out @J_H)

Comment: My suggested solution may not take quite as much of a performance hit if you force the entire column to string before uploading: `df_final = df_final.astype({'Value': numpy.str})`. There may still be a bit of a slowdown because of the nulls, but there is (currently) [not much we can do about that](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/741).